# How to bypass Immunities that counter Enervation effects

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, immunities

We are fighting a lot of high level demons, it is probably going to be worse.

My Wizard is specialized on [Enervation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enervation) ([Spell Perfection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-perfection), Mythic).   I am looking for ways to deliver the spell even if I face the immunities of [Demon Lords](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules) like *Ability Damage, Ability Drain, Death Effects, and Energy Drain.*
Can these immunities be overcome?

I know about the [Fireball Augmented Version](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic/augmented-spells#TOC-Enervation) that can bypass fire immunity, so it looks like there are ways bypassing immunities. I know that there is not a comparable augmented version of Enervation.

**What are other ways to bypass these immunities?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Thanatopic Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/thanatopic-spell-metamagic)

**A thanatopic spell pierces** defenses and **immunities** that protect against death effects, **negative levels, and energy drain**, affecting the target as if the protective barrier did not exist.

---

<sub>**Note:**</sub>

If a GM has the opinion this is for only for undead, it is probably intended with undead immunities in mind; the language itself makes it inclusive and exclusive.

> The descriptive text:
>
> Your spells can pierce wards against negative energy ***and*** even affect undead targets.

***And***, in this case, is a definite "in addition to."

> The normal effects text:
>
> Defenses such as death ward negate death effects, negative levels, and energy drain. ***Undead are immune to these attacks.***

***Undead are immune to these attacks,*** in this case, is a separate sentence, which is separate, but related to, the previous sentence.

Comment: I would make sure to double check with your GM before using the feat, it specifically calls out wards and undead as its intended use; just verify that they agree it also affects your intended targets. I'm not saying this answer is wrong, but with a slightly different reading, your GM might rule against it for your table.

Comment: @Ifusaso You're referring to the _example_ provided in the feat.

Comment: Actually I'm referring to the flavor text and the 'as opposed to' line: "Normal: Defenses such as death ward negate death effects, negative levels, and energy drain. Undead are immune to these attacks." As I said, I don't disagree with the answer, and upvoted it. I just thought this a good addition since some GM's might rule different.

Comment: @Ifusaso Edited to include your position.

Comment: If a GM rules different he isn't going by raw on his decision, which is fine as he is the GM.

Comment: "Such as" is never an exclusive list. And it has been said by the devs that fluff text is never valid as rules if they oppose what the rules say.

Comment: @ShadowKras I believe I originally stated that I don't disagree, but the wording could *easily* be RAI into referring to spell and undead protection. I would personally allow it to apply, but when I originally read it, I wasn't sure. Specific trumps general and all that. Regardless, I don't think there's a better answer so that's that.

Comment: As i was told once on this site, RAI should never be taken into consideration unless we know what the author wanted. So, if we don't know what the devs have to say about it, then it's not RAI, we only have RAW and our personal opinions.

Comment: In this case, the feat is *normally* applied against undead, as undead are the types of creature that will often (to not say *always*) have protection from negative drain and death effects, but as listed on another question by the same author, there are more creature with that special ability (ie: umbral dragons and vemleks).

Comment: The wording on Thanatopic Spell is very different from Threnodic Spell, also from the same book: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/threnodic-spell-metamagic